# Pandas Dataframe.to_sql wrongly inserting into more than one table (postgresql)

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pandas

> df.to_sql(name='hourly', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

It inserts data not only to table 'hourly', but also to table 'margin' - I execute this particular line only.
It's Postgresql 10.
While Creating table 'hourly', I inherited column names and dtypes from table 'margin'.

Is it something wrong with the db itself or is it Python code?

Comment: Please format your code using code formatter. Doesn't looks anything wrong with you code. Check your DB table create statements.

Comment: what is the reason you inherited this table instead of using regular `CREATE TABLE ...` statement?

Comment: @RehanAzher thanks for the hint with CREATE statements - that did it. MaxU - I used PgAdmin4 GUI and selected another table to inherit columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.to_sql(name='hourly', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

will insert rows from the `df` DataFrame into `hourly` table using SQL Alchemy - no more, no less.

The rest will be done on the PostgreSQL side.

Answer (score 0):

Removing

> INHERITS (tablename);

on the slave table (creating it again without INHERITS)
seems to have done the trick.

Only a matter of curiosity:
Why did it matter? I thought inheritance only gets columns and dtypes not the actual data.